# ThreeJS is not casting shadows

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am building a basic Three JS application. Basically, I am learning Three JS and so that I am experimenting with it. Now, I am building a scene where there is a floor, an object and a light. I want to see the shadow of the object on the floor due to light. This is my code.

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const aspect_ratio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspect_ratio, 1, 10000);
camera.position.z = 500;
scene.add(camera);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.append(renderer.domElement);

var shape = new THREE.TorusGeometry(100, 50, 8, 20);
var cover = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
cover.emissive.setRGB(0.8, 0.1, 0.1);
cover.specular.setRGB(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
var donut = new THREE.Mesh(shape, cover); scene.add(donut);
donut.castShadow = true;

var sunlight = new THREE.DirectionalLight();
sunlight.intensity = 0.5;
sunlight.position.set(100, 100, 100);
scene.add(sunlight);
sunlight.castShadow = true;

var shape = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1500, 1500);
var cover = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
var ground = new THREE.Mesh(shape, cover);
scene.add(ground);
ground.position.set(0, -180, 0);
ground.rotation.set(-Math.PI/2, 0, 0);
ground.receiveShadow = true;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
```

I am supposed to see the shadow of the donut on the floor. But this is what I see instead without shadow.

[image]

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Basic material is not affected by lights. Try using Phong. And set receiveShadow = true. https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshBasicMaterial

Comment: Actually, there’s a lot more missing from your shadow setup. Did you follow the sample code in the docs? It’s all there: https://threejs.org/docs/?q=shadow#api/en/lights/shadows/DirectionalLightShadow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code. The most important problem is that you do not configure your shadow frustum correctly. Besides, `MeshBasicMaterial` is not affected by light and thus can't receive shadows. Try it like so:

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const aspect_ratio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspect_ratio, 1, 10000);
camera.position.z = 500;
scene.add(camera);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.append(renderer.domElement);

const donutGeometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(100, 50, 8, 20);
const donutMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
donutMaterial.emissive.setRGB(0.8, 0.1, 0.1);
donutMaterial.specular.setRGB(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
const donut = new THREE.Mesh(donutGeometry, donutMaterial); 
scene.add(donut);
donut.castShadow = true;

var sunlight = new THREE.DirectionalLight();
sunlight.intensity = 0.5;
sunlight.position.set(100, 100, 100);
scene.add(sunlight);
sunlight.castShadow = true;
sunlight.shadow.camera.top = 200;
sunlight.shadow.camera.bottom = - 200;
sunlight.shadow.camera.left = - 200;
sunlight.shadow.camera.right = 200;
sunlight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
sunlight.shadow.camera.far = 1000;

//scene.add( new THREE.CameraHelper( sunlight.shadow.camera ) );

const groundGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1500, 1500);
const groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
const ground = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeometry, groundMaterial);
scene.add(ground);
ground.position.set(0, -180, 0);
ground.rotation.set(-Math.PI/2, 0, 0);
ground.receiveShadow = true;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.144/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It works. Could you please give me explanation around `sunlight.shadow.camera.top = 200;
sunlight.shadow.camera.bottom = - 200;
sunlight.shadow.camera.left = - 200;
sunlight.shadow.camera.right = 200;
sunlight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
sunlight.shadow.camera.far = 1000;`?

Comment: This configures the shadow camera's view frustum. You can visualize it by commenting in the line with `CameraHelper`. Only objects inside this frustum will cast and receive shadows from the respective light.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know why those values are used as I don't understand the concept too. Could you please give me a link to tutorial where I can learn more about it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the ground to receive shadow

to do this:

```
ground.receiveShadow = true;
```

Comment: The OP already has this line of code in its snippet.